# Trying to setup Snorby: dm-active_model-1.2.1 cannot be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, snort

I am trying to setup snorby on backtrack5 R3 because it looks cool and my boss wants it there.  Also, backtrack comes with snort already installed which makes my job easier.  After making sure everything was installed and fighting numerous other problems, I started getting errors with dm-active_model-1.2.1  It has been saying things like "Could not find dm-active_model-1.2.1 in any of the sources.  Whenever I put in bundle install from within the snorby folder, it spits out what looks like the source code for the gem...I'll post it below.

```
WARNING:  #<ArgumentError: Illformed requirement ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0xa54414c> 1.2.3"]>
 # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = %q{dm-active_model}
  s.version = "1.2.1"

  s.required_rubygems_version = Gem::Requirement.new(">= 0") if 
s.respond_to? :required_rubygems_version=
  s.authors = ["Martin Gamsjaeger (snusnu)"]
  s.date = %q{2012-02-15 00:00:00.000000000Z}
  s.description = %q{A datamapper plugin for active_model compliance and thus rails 3 compatibility.}
  s.email = %q{gamsnjaga [a] gmail [d] com}
  s.extra_rdoc_files = ["LICENSE", "README.rdoc", "TODO"]
  s.files = [".document", "CHANGELOG", "Gemfile", "LICENSE", "README.rdoc", "Rakefile", "TODO", "VERSION", "dm-active_model.gemspec", "lib/dm-active_model.rb", "lib/dm-active_model/version.rb", "spec/amo_interface_compliance_spec.rb", "spec/amo_validation_compliance_spec.rb", "spec/dm-active_model_spec.rb", "spec/lib/amo_lint_extensions.rb", "spec/rcov.opts", "spec/spec.opts", "tasks/changelog.rake", "tasks/spec.rake", "tasks/yard.rake", "tasks/yardstick.rake"]
  s.homepage = %q{http://github.com/datamapper/dm-active_model}
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]
  s.rubyforge_project = %q{datamapper}
  s.rubygems_version = %q{1.3.7}
  s.summary = %q{active_model compliance for datamapper}

  if s.respond_to? :specification_version then
    current_version = Gem::Specification::CURRENT_SPECIFICATION_VERSION
    s.specification_version = 3

    if Gem::Version.new(Gem::VERSION) >= Gem::Version.new('1.2.0') then
      s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<dm-core>, ["~> 1.2.0"])
      s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<activemodel>, ["~> 3.0"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<dm-validations>, ["~> 1.2.0"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<jeweler>, ["~> 1.6.4"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<rake>, ["~> 0.9.2"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<rspec>, ["~> 1.3.2"])
      s.add_development_dependency(%q<test-unit>, ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0xa54414c> 1.2.3"])
    else
      s.add_dependency(%q<dm-core>, ["~> 1.2.0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<activemodel>, ["~> 3.0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<dm-validations>, ["~> 1.2.0"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<jeweler>, ["~> 1.6.4"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<rake>, ["~> 0.9.2"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<rspec>, ["~> 1.3.2"])
      s.add_dependency(%q<test-unit>, ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0xa54414c> 1.2.3"])
    end
  else
    s.add_dependency(%q<dm-core>, ["~> 1.2.0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<activemodel>, ["~> 3.0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<dm-validations>, ["~> 1.2.0"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<jeweler>, ["~> 1.6.4"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<rake>, ["~> 0.9.2"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<rspec>, ["~> 1.3.2"])
    s.add_dependency(%q<test-unit>, ["#<Syck::DefaultKey:0xa54414c> 1.2.3"])
  end
end
WARNING:  Invalid .gemspec format in '/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/specifications/dm-active_model- 1.2.1.gemspec'
Could not find dm-active_model-1.2.1 in any of the sources
```

EDIT:
Now I am running in Ubuntu 11 32 bit.  I am coming up with the same continuous issue...

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 1.9.3 or higher is required for Snorby. Since you mentioned simplification, take a look at Security Onion. It has Snort and Snorby all set up, as well as many other tools.